# L'usage du pronom « en » avec « être d'accord » dans ce cas-là est-il correct?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

- Tout le monde dit « Je suis d'accord » ou « Je suis d'accord avec [telle chose/telle personne] ».
- Le pronom *en* peut être utilisé pour reprendre de l'information.

Ma question est la suivante: Est-ce qu'on peut dire « J'en suis d'accord », considérant les deux points ci-dessus?

Answer (score 3):

On peut être d'accord (ou **en accord**) **avec** quelque chose / quelqu'un, et non être d'accord **de** quelque chose / quelqu'un.

L'expression **J'en suis d'accord** est rarement voire même quasi jamais utilisée dans le langage courant.

Comment: "être d'accord avec" + nom ou pronom ; "être d'accord de ou pour" + verbe.  "J'en suis d'accord", fréquent dans les classiques (par ex, une des premières recherche dans [google books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=a2KIoNaXvYAC&pg=PA308&dq=j%27en+suis+d%27accord&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=LIfGU8_rI4Sn0QXh3oD4BQ&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=j%27en%20suis%20d%27accord&f=false)). C'est un peu désuet de nos jours mais néanmoins employé. Quelle est ta source qui dit que c'est agrammatical

Comment: C'est plus que désuet !

Answer (score 0):

On peut être d'accord **avec** quelqu'un ou quelque chose :

> - [Nous sommes d’accord avec le directeur général [...]](http://www.liberation.fr/economie/2014/07/31/l-omc-echoue-a-adopter-un-texte-conclu-en-decembre-a-bali_1073802)
> - [Nous sommes d’accord avec la politique de la Maison-Blanche.[...]](http://mondafrique.com/lire/editos/2014/07/12/affaire-alstom-la-trahison-des-elites-francaises)

On peut aussi être d'accord **sur** ou **de** quelque chose :

> - [D'une part, la neutralité des espaces officiels doit être préservée, et nous sommes d'accord là-dessus.](http://books.google.fr/books?id=E1JvNgB6cnkC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22d%27accord%20l%C3%A0-dessus%22&source=bl&ots=8ZfBjGLDRN&sig=o7Al72fvJjRalC9MaRFidgOlT0Y&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=YFjsU_eNIOma1AWrrYGQBg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22d%27accord%20l%C3%A0-dessus%22&f=false)
> - [Tous sont d’accord là-dessus](http://www.lavenir.net/article/detail.aspx?articleid=DMF20120929_00211390)
> - [[...] toujours pas d'accord sur un gouvernement d'unité [...]](http://www.rfi.fr/afrique/20140811-soudan-sud-toujours-pas-accord-gouvernement-unite/)
> - On croira, Madame, que vous êtes d'accord de tout ce qui se passe (Chateaubriand)
> - [les parties concernées doivent être d’accord de soumettre le litige à la Commission](http://www.curbain.be/fr/renover-construire-et-conserver/architectes-et-entrepreneurs/commission-de-conciliation-construction)
> - [[...] nous sommes d’accord de faire des sacrifices, [...]](http://www.tdg.ch/vivre/Catherine-Armand-Touch--n-Dance--Danse-urbaine-impromptue/story/20845053)

Grevisse (ed. 1975) signale que l'emploi de **sur** dans ce cas-là est le plus fréquent de nos jours et

> on dit aussi d'accord **en** :  ils sont d'accord *sur ce point* ou *en ce point*.

On peut aussi être d'accord **pour** (faire) quelque chose :

> [[...] la France et le Royaume-Uni étaient d’accord pour participer à l’aide humanitaire [...]](http://www.france24.com/fr/20140809-irak-EIIL-france-royaume-uni-soutenir-effort-humanitaire-obama/)

**En** était très présent dans la littérature classique mais semble en perte de vitesse de nos jours. On peut certainement parler de régionalisme parce qu'il y a des régions de France où la présence du *en* est systématique chez beaucoup de locuteurs. Par exemple je l'entends dans une partie de l'ouest de la France, alors que je ne l'ai jamais entendu dans le sud ouest. On le trouve aussi par écrit comme le montrent quelques exemples pris dans la presse récente :

> - [Nous en sommes bien d'accord : ce que l'on voit fleurir depuis fin janvier au pied des conteneurs](http://valdeloir.revolublog.com/la-loi-toute-la-loi-a108632888) (21 Juillet 2014)
> - [Que j'ouvre un compte, j'en suis d'accord, que je maintienne dessus un encours régulier de 1.000 à 2.000 euros, oui encore](http://www.lanouvellerepublique.fr/France-Monde/Communautes-NR/Dialogue/n/Contenus/Articles/2014/08/07/Le-remboursement-du-pret-seul-engagement-contractuel-2006983) (7 août 2014)
> - [Moi, j'en suis d'accord et je crois qu'il faut que la loi précise les conditions dans lesquelles on accède aux fadettes](http://www.liberation.fr/societe/2011/10/31/gueant-d-accord-pour-legiferer-et-supprimer-les-ambiguites-des-fadettes_771583) (31 oct 2011)
> - [j’en suis d’accord](http://ripostelaique.com/courrier-des-lecteurs-a-roubaix-je-me-suis-cru-en-territoire-occupe.html) (4 août 2014)
> - [on ne peut qu'en être d'accord](http://www.slate.fr/tribune/79747/idees-economie-folles) (novembre 2013)

Comment: Est-ce que dans ces même régions les gens emploient « Je suis d'accord de [cela] » ? Ce n'est pas habituel de remplacer un groupe introduit par *avec* ou *pour* par *en*.

Comment: La reprise n'implique pas la reprise d'un groupe de mot contenant *avec* *de* ou *sur*, c'est la reprise d'un point de vue qui vient d'être exprimé, que ce soit par un locuteur différent ou par soi-même. Le *en* est confirmé par Grevisse, on trouve de nombreux exemples de « être d'accord de quelque chose » en Belgique, je ne sais pas si en Belgique ils emploient beaucoup « en être d'accord », mais « en être d'accord », se dit,  a l'aval du Dictionnaire de l'Adacadémie et de Grevisse dont on peut dire que c'est tout à fait grammatical et correct.